# Unity Desktop "freezes" but can be recovered with xkill

Tags: 16.04, unity, xkill

I'm running 16.04 with Unity desktop enviro, and periodically my desktop environment looses responsiveness.  It often happens when I open Blender, Krita, Cura, and many other apps (just did it now when I opened the Calculator!)

The mouse still moves, but I can't click anything.  I've discovered that I can recover my opening a terminal with the keyboard, then using `xkill`.  I click anywhere on the screen and `xkill` causes the screen to flash, like it's killing some overlay that covered the entire screen blocking me from clicking anything.  Then everything works again.

xkill doesn't actually kill the app that seemed to trigger the "freeze", all apps are still running fine.

How do I fix this?

EDIT

Just occured again.  Here's the output of `xprop`:

```
$ xprop
_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 5, 710, 54, 54
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_TAKE_FOCUS
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: False
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Hud"
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 7753
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "mymachine"
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_STICKY, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER

$ xkill
Select the window whose client you wish to kill with button 1....
xkill:  killing creator of resource 0x320001c
```

Comment: Strange! Try `xprop` instead of `xkill` to extract some info about the overlay.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the details.  Also, I noticed this time it only affected one monitor of my two.  Not sure if that was always the case or not.